# combining separate .tx files into a thesis

Tags: thesis, combine

I need help.

I have three projects with different preembles and structure.

They are paper1.tex, paper2.tex, paper3.tex

Now i want to combine these three different papers into chapters under one file.

instead of bringing parts the traditional way, i just want ccomhow bring the three tex together without damaging their structure or anythying following the content page.

Can you help please

I am working in overleaf

Comment: How much are you willing to adapt the tex of paperX?  If you delete the preamble, you can `input` or `include` the rest.  If you want paperX with no changes, you can try the pdfpages package to includepdf each paperX.pdf.  You can also look into the standalone package, which might be between those two options.

Comment: Hi , this is good if I good bring in the pdfpages....Can you give me a standard code on how to try those out?